# Finding the shortest list in a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, minimum, type-mismatch

I am having some difficulty with a program I've written using Haskell. The idea behind it is to recursively find the shortest list in a list of lists and return that. I've managed to write the program okay but I can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong in it. These are the errors that I get when I try to compile it:

- Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[[a]]’, ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for: shortest :: forall a. [[a]] -> [a] at shortest.hs:1:13. Expected type: [[[a]]], Actual type: [a]
- In the first argument of ‘shortest’, namely ‘y’. In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘shortest y’. In the expression: shortest y : [list]
- Relevant bindings include list :: [[a]] (bound at shortest.hs:4:15), y :: [a] (bound at shortest.hs:4:13), x :: [a] (bound at shortest.hs:4:11), shortest :: [[a]] -> [a] (bound at shortest.hs:2:1).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
shortest :: [[a]] -> [a]
shortest [] = []
shortest [y] = y
shortest (x:y:list)
   | length x > length y = shortest y:[list]
   | otherwise = shortest x:[list]
```

If anyone could give me any pointers as to where I'm going wrong it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you just need parentheses. `shortest (y:[list])` and the same for the x case. The precedence of `:` makes it read like `(shortest y) : [list]`

Comment: @jkeuhlen thank you! I literally just spotted that myself, been looking at it so long I wasn't seeing the obvious!

Comment: glad that helped. I added it as an answer since that's the more permanent place for these kinds of things rather than comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list` is already the tail of your input; you don't need to (nor should you) wrap it in another list.

```
shortest (x:y:list) = shortest $ (if length x > length y then y else x) : list
```

At each step, it's just a question of which element, `x` or `y`, you remove from the input to the recursive call.

Another way, which doesn't require two base cases, is to just compare the head of the list to the result of recursing on the tail.

```
shortest [] = []
shortest (x:xs) = let s = shortest xs
                  in if length s < length x then s else x
```

Finally, tuples compare lexicographically, so you can also dispense with explicit recursion by tagging each list with its length, finding the smallest tagged value, then extracting the original list.

```
shortest = snd . minimum . map (\x -> (length x, x))
```

Using `Control.Arrow`, you can write the argument to `map` as `(length &&& id)`.

Caveat for the last approach: since lists also compare lexicographically, the final result if you have multiple lists with the shortest length will depend on how the list values themselves compare. The first two examples, by contrast, are stable; the first such shortest list is returned.

---

Daniel Wagner points out a better solution for using `minimum`, which is to wrap each element in an `Arg` value which lets two lists be compared *solely* on their lengths, without considering the lists' contents.

```
import Data.Semigroup
shortest xs = x where Arg _ x = minimum [Arg (length x) x | x <- xs]
```

`Arg` is basically a 2-element product type which *only* uses the first element for its `Ord` instance, unlike `(,)` which uses both.

Comment: Your final solution has the downside that it requires an `Ord a` constraint, and with many lists of the same length may do much more work. Consider using [`Arg`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Arg) instead of a tuple to alleviate these two problems (note its `instance Ord a => Ord (Arg a b)` which does not require `Ord b` in its context).

Comment: Yes, that's a bigger issue than the one I pointed out. Is there a better way to unwrap the `Arg` value in the end? Also, is there a way to simplify that using `ArgMin`?

Comment: For a complete worked solution, consider `shortest xs = x where Arg _ x = minimum [Arg (length x) x | x <- xs]`. You can use `ArgMin`, but it's a bit noisier syntactically.

Answer (score 4):

```
  shortest []=[]
  shortest [y] = y
  shortest (x:y:list)
   |length x > length y = shortest (y:list)            
   |otherwise = shortest (x:list)
```

This works :), also worth mentioning is if you have 2 or several elements in the list which are "shortest" the first element will always pop out.

i.e.

```
   Prelude>shortest[[1],[2],[3]]
   [1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
shortest list = minimumBy (comparing length) list
```

point-free:

```
shortest = minimumBy (comparing length)
```

These libraries are included with GHC. Their names say what they do pretty well. Perhaps add in a separate case for empty list.

Comment: Or even `minimumBy $ comparing length`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need parentheses: `shortest (y:list)` and the same for the `x` case.

The precedence of `:` makes it read like `(shortest y) : list`

Comment: right, although, `(y:[list])` is also wrong. you need to correct that. ( `(1:[2]) == [1,2]` ).

Comment: @WillNess Thanks! Fixed now. I just threw this together as a quick comment and moved it to an answer when the OP said it worked for them. I probably should have done more due diligence in the comment->answer transition.